# rest api to know if a record belonging to any entity is public or not

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Is there any REST API through which I can know if any record belonging to any entity type is public or not?

Actually, I want to perform some kind of action in my Javascript code on the basis of the value that if a record is public or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "public" - have you created a field called `new_public` or similar?

Comment: @jasonscript, thank you so much for the reply. Through 'public', I mean that I want to know if a particular record is having user-level or team-level permissions on it or not. I want to treat all the records as public records on which there is no team or user-level access imposed. Any user belonging to the same business unit as that of the record should access it, if it is not having the user or team permissions.

Comment: The Rest API runs in the context of a user, so if a user does not have permission to read a record, then it will not be returned in the Rest API results. I'm not sure that I understand your question 100%